# How to use Javascript event preventDefault() function inside a function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, preventdefault

I want to do something like this:

**HTML code:**

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="#" onclick="myfun()">Click Me </a>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
function myfun(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("OK");
}
```

**I know we can code like below :**

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", 
function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("OK");
});
```

**But I want something like above mentioned**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: Why do you want inline JS? The latter example is much better.

Comment: Some times in life we need to compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `event` in the function call in the element:

```js
function myfun(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("OK");
}
```

```html
<a id="myAnchor" href="#" onclick="myfun(event)">Click Me </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="#" onclick="myfun(event)">Click Me </a>
```